# how can i send clickable link to user via sms in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Hi im trying to send a resetpassword link to a user via sms just the same way you send it using password reset for email in mvc

the code i have ryt now just sends me an sms with the full url and Id of user only not the part where i ca click

here is my reset for email code first to show how i reset

```
   [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        //SendSmsBusiness objap = new SendSmsBusiness();
        RegisterBusiness reg = new RegisterBusiness();
        EmailBusiness _emailBusiness = new EmailBusiness();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            user = reg.UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            if (user != null)
            {
                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol:Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                _emailBusiness.SendEmailForgot(model.Email, callbackUrl);
                return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user does not exist");
                return View();
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

this works fyn

and here is my code for my sms reset

```
   // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult PhoneReset()
    {
        return View();
    }
    // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PhoneReset(ForgotPasswordView model,string sms)
    {
        RegisterBusiness reg = new RegisterBusiness();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            user = reg.UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            if (user != null)
            {
                //string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

                SendSmsBusiness objap = new SendSmsBusiness();

                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                sms =  "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";
                objap.Send_SMS(model.Phone, sms);
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("ResetViaPhone", "Account");
            }
            else if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user does not exist");
                return View();
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

in the sms i just get this - please reset your password by clicking

but there is no link.
minenhle@gmail.com is the im using to resetpassword for.

i don,t know where im getting it wrong or what im trying is not possible

Answer (score 2):

SMS messages aren't HTML, so they don't understand an anchor tag.  Most devices will make things that look like a URL clickable however, but that is up to the device you are sending to.  Also, Url.Action will generate a relative URL, since it's not on a page, you need to create a fully qualified URL.

```
sms =  "Please reset your password by clicking " + callbackUrl;
```

Comment: i tried that before but it still giving me    -Please reset your password by clicking http://localhost:55624/Account/ResetPassword?userId=nameofuserid                                                                                                                                                                      it just gives me the direct url not the link

Comment: im looking for a workaround this though.that is my problem

Comment: There isn't one.  What you are trying to do would be a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="sms:recepient Phone #;?&body=My Name is- %20Kamlesh%20Gathe">
     Click here to text me
/a>
```

%20 is used to give space.

This link can be embedded in email anywhere.